# AWS Api Gateway Cors localhost

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cognito

I have created an AWS HTTP API gateway. It maps to my lambda function.
I have enabled JWT type authorization on my routes, it uses a cognito pool.

Calling the API from insomnia/postman with the auth token added works and returns as expected.

The CORS policy for the HTTP API is set in the following way:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-cors:
  allowMethods:
  - "DELETE"
  - "GET"
  - "HEAD"
  - "OPTIONS"
  - "PATCH"
  - "POST"
  - "PUT"
  allowHeaders:
  - "*"
  - "accept"
  - "access-control-allow-origin"
  - "authorization"
  - "content-type"
  exposeHeaders:
  - "*"
  - "accept"
  - "access-control-allow-origin"
  - "authorization"
  - "content-type"
  maxAge: 600
  allowCredentials: true
  allowOrigins:
  - "http://localhost:19006/"
```

I see the preflight OPTIONS request to my URL, and I also see that it gets 401 response for it, and doesn't return the set headers as above.

How can I enable cors while also having the cognito JWT type authorization?

Edit: I am sending the request from react side this way:

```
fetch('<URL>', { credentials: 'include', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,'content-type': 'text/html' }, redirect: 'follow', mode: 'cors' })
```

Comment: I would like to also add, that I am indeed calling my API from http://localhost:19006/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware react doesn't send an authorisation header to the OPTIONS pre flight request. So if you've added authorisation to this path it will always respond with a 401. The OPTIONS resource should not have authorisation placed on it.

Comment: I though the CORS settings in the aws API gateway settings were to free me from the burden of dealing with preflight requests from the API side. If i understand correctly, I need to implement my own lambda to respond to the options requests with the cors headers set? Whats the cors settings in aws there for then I dont really understand?

Comment: I'm not sure under what use case one may want to protect the OPTIONS resource, I'm guessing someone else on here may know. But you don't need to handle the pre flight OPTIONS request using a lambda (although you could if you want). I would recommend using the AWS API gateway mock response for the OPTIONS resource.

Comment: ended up using your suggestion